# How to set Timeout for a specific sql query?

Tags: sql-server, timeout, settimeout, qsqlquery

I want to set Timeout value for a specific sql query which will execute inside a stored procedure.
Is it possible to set the timeout value for a particular query?

Comment: why you are trying to use in sql instead of using in .net or java

Comment: SQL Server won't stop running your query, you should set the timeout in the client from where you perform the connection. If it's SSMS you can use `sp_configure`

Comment: I'm using .Net in front end and there is an option from SqlCommand to set the timeout like command.CommandTimeout = 10000. Are you referring this to me? @Mani

Comment: yes you are correct @gopal

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I'm looking for the same option for a stored procedure in SQL Server. @ Mani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the client API rather than SQL Server that enforces query timeouts (RPC or batch).  Consequently, you can't set a client command timeout at a more granular level when a stored procedure contains multiple statements.  You'll need to split the proc such that the desired query is executed separately by the client, and specify a different timeout for that command.

The specifics of how to set the timeout vary depending on the client API.  In the case of .NET, it is the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property.

Comment: Suppose the proc contains only one query then what is the way to specify timeout for that proc? Is it from front end like .Net/ java... SqlCommand? @Dan Guzman

Comment: The `CommandTimeout` property of `.Net SqlCommand` will control the timeout.  From Java, I think it depends on the driver (e.g. supports `setQueryTimeout()` method.